# Interface 'IteratorAggregate' not found in Google App Engine Standard

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-php

I am trying to run wordpress on Google App Engine Standard PHP, and am receiving this log error when accessing admin: Interface 'IteratorAggregate' not found. Is there something special that needs to occur to get this working?

Comment: Running into this error on app engine, not using wordpress. Did you ever solve it?